# Using jquery on text typing for contenteditable and contains specific text show div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show hidden div after typing in the content editable tag if we type "$" in the starting. I tried using below attached code. Please help me with this

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".title span").keydown(function(){
            $(".title span").change(function() {
              var conattr = $(this).attr('contenteditable');
              if (typeof conattr !== typeof undefined && conattr !== false) {
              //if p tag as attribute contenteditable
              if ($("title span:contains('$')")){
              //alert('hello')
                $("hidden-box").show();
              }
            } else {
            }
            }).trigger("change");
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <h1 class="title">Hello World
      <span contenteditable="true">
       <div class="hidden-box">
        <p>I am a Hidden Box</p>
       </div>
      </span>
     </h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the hidden-box when you enter $ in the hidden-box?

Comment: No not in hidden-box but in span I mean out of hidden box

Comment: Show hidden-box when typing $ in span?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put `.` in `$("hidden-box").show();` now its working 
same for `title span`
i have also changed `span` to `div` since span does not have width and its hard to click on it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".title .showHiddenBoxDiv").keydown(function() {
        $(".title .showHiddenBoxDiv").change(function() {
            var conattr = $(this).attr('contenteditable');
            if (typeof conattr !== typeof undefined && conattr !== false) {
                if ($(".showHiddenBoxDiv").html().indexOf("$") == 0) {
                    $(".hidden-box").show();
                }
            } else {}
        }).trigger("change");
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden-box{
display: none;
}

.showHiddenBoxDiv{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <h1 class="title">Hello World
  <div contenteditable="true" class="showHiddenBoxDiv">
   <div class="hidden-box">
    <p>I am a Hidden Box</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </h1>
</div>
```